# Packing binomial functions in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

I would like to pack binomial functions with different parameters in a list. Here the binomial functions are defined as follows:

```
px[x_, k_, n_] := 1 - \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(k\)]\(Binomial[n, i] x^i\ \((1 - x)\)^\((n - i)\)\)\)

py[y_, k_, n_] := \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(k\)]\(Binomial[n, i] y^\((n - i)\)\ \((1 - y)\)^i\)\)
```

When `n` is given, I need to find a list

```
{(1/2)(px[x, k, n]+py[y, k, n]):k=0,1,...,n-1}
```

For example if `n=2`

```
{(1/2)(px[x, 0, 2]+py[y, 0, 2]),(1/2)(px[x, 1, 2]+py[y, 1, 2])}
```

and for `n=3`

```
{(1/2)(px[x, 0, 3]+py[y, 0, 3]),(1/2)(px[x, 1, 3]+py[y, 1, 3],(1/2)(px[x, 2, 3]+py[y, 2, 3])}
```

etc.

> How can Mathematica do this automatically for me when I just give the value of $n$? So I am looking forwards to obtaining a list of functions, each of which is dependent on two variables $x$ and $y$

Comment: It might be better to ask your questions one at a time

Comment: @mikado I agree but I just had the idea that both questions are quite related and if one can answer the second one, which is actually the one that I am looking for, he/she would also be able to answer the first one.

Comment: `BernsteinBasis[]` is built-in, so you could just do e.g. `py[y_, k_, n_] := Sum[BernsteinBasis[n, i, y], {i, 0, k}]`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. And where can I use this? I am not able to create the lists still.. Maybe I must separate this question into two.

Comment: The question is now separated in to two and other part can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182773/definition-of-a-recursive-formula

Comment: Can't you just do `Table[(px[x, k, n]+py[y, k, n])/2, {k, 0, n - 1}]`?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. yes. thats exatly the thing that I am looking for. So okay. Next time I know what to use at least for this kind of problems. You can post an asnwer.